# Convert array to NSAttributedString

Tags: arrays, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsattributedstring

I have a `NSMutableArray` composed of `NSAttributedString`'s.

I'm trying to convert it to a single `NSAttributedString` separating all the `NSAttributedString`'s with a character.

This approach is similar to the conversion of an array to a `NSString` with the `componentsJoinedByString:@","` method but unfortunately this method doesn't exist with the `NSAttributedString`.

How can I convert the array? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd to the old way:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
NSAttributedString *jointElement = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@","]
for (int i = 0; i < [yourArray count] -1; i ++)
{
    [attrStr appendAttributedString:[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [attrStr appendAttributedString:jointElement];
}
[attrStr appendAttributedString:[yourArray lastObject]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a result mutable attributed string and a 'spacer' character string, iterate the array and append the string from the array and the spacer to the result string (unless this is the last iteration, then don't add the spacer).