# Display edited NSString in order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsattributedstring

I have been working on this for a few days with help from this great community.

I have a `NSArray` that I need to edit `NSStrings` within. I have managed to detect a marker in the string and make it bold. However now I am trying to display the strings in the order that they are within the NSArray whilst maintaining the Bold that was added to the specific strings.

I can display the individual Bold String '`string`' but I need it to be in order that it is within the array. I know of `stringByAppendingString` but this would put it at the end.

Any directions would be brilliant.

```
for (NSString *testWord in legislationArray) {
            if ([testWord rangeOfString:@"BOLDME"].location != NSNotFound) {

            //Remove Marker
            NSString *stripped = [testWord stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"BOLDME" withString:@""];

            //Get string and add bold
            NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stripped];

            NSRange selectedRange = [stripped rangeOfString:(stripped)];

            [string beginEditing];

            [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                           value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0]
                           range:selectedRange];

            [string endEditing];

            //Where to go now with string?

        }
    }
    cell.dynamicLabel.text = [legislationArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

**EDIT**

Based on the answers below I got it working however the bold method invokes this error:

[image]

Comment: Your additional issue is not a error - this is a way how XCode shows attributed strings in debug window. I have added screenshot to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use additional array. Change your code to

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
for (NSString *testWord in legislationArray) {
    if ([testWord rangeOfString:@"BOLDME"].location != NSNotFound) {

        //Remove Marker
        NSString *stripped = [testWord stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"BOLDME" withString:@""];

        //Get string and add bold
        NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stripped];

        NSRange selectedRange = [stripped rangeOfString:(stripped)];

        [string beginEditing];

        [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                       value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0]
                       range:selectedRange];

        [string endEditing];

        //Where to go now with string?
        [attrString appendAttributedString:string];
    }
    else
    {
        [attrString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:testWord]];
    }
    // NEW LINE
    [attrString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];
}
cell.dynamicLabel.attributedText = attrString;
```

UPDATE:

Your additional issue is not a error - this is a way how XCode shows attributed strings in debug window:
[image]

Comment: This works. However it produces a weird error on the bold as shown in the updated answer. Any suggestions?

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone I have improved the answer. Please check it.

Comment: looks good. Only problem now is I have lost where to put componentsJoinedByString:@"\n" as from reading up on it this isn't supported by attributedString

Comment: Add the "\n" before appending.

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone I have added '[attrString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];' to the answer.

Comment: Note that you add a "useless" "\n" at the end of your `NSAttributedString`. That why, in the link given in my answer, I used the `for each`, but a classic `for` loop.

Comment: @Larme it is not a problem to delete the last symbol of a string using 'deleteCharactersInRange' method.

Comment: I know, but it's just in case to inform the author if it made him a "higher" result and want to get rid of it, helping him understand that there is a "\n" at the end.

Answer (score 3):

`componentsJoinedByString` return a `NSString`, when you want a `NSAttributedString`.
Plus, you're setting your text to a receiver that awaits a `NSString` (`cell.dynamicLabel.text`), where what you want should be `cell.dynamicLabel.attributedText`.

Since there is no equivalent to `componentsJoinedByString` for a `NSAttributedString` return, you have to do it the oldway, with a `for` loop, starting with initializing a `NSMutableAttributedString`, and adding to it each components (that you may "transform") to it.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368237/convert-array-to-nsattributedstring) is a example and related question.